# How to correctly get the file/stream position pointers in C++ for an input/output stream?

Tags: c++, stringstream

If I have a `std::stringstream` variable and I wrote some `std::string objects` in it, and I want to be able to track the stream position pointers and output them on the screen, how do I use the `tellp()`
and then later on when I extract from the stream i.e. using the stream for input, how do I use `tellg()`.
How do I open the stream in input mode again?  Also, should I set the position pointer back to 0 with `seekg()` or `seekp()` when I open it back again for input?

Here is my code

```cpp
std::string word;
std::stringstream ss;

while (word != "n") {
  std::cout << "Enter a word, ( n to stop) : ";
  std::cin >> word;
  std::cin.ignore();
  if (word == "n")
    ss << std::endl;
  else {
    ss << word;
    ss << " ";
  }
}

std::cout << "The content in stringstream is : " << ss.str() << std::endl;

std::cout << "The StreamPositionPointer is"
          << ss.tellp();  // is this correct way of outputting streampointer

// how should I open the stream to get input from it to store it in a variable?

/* how should I switch the position pointer to a position when I use an
   input/output stream like sstream with seekg(), seekp(), tellg(),tellp() */
```

Comment: Yes, see [std::basic_stringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the basic idea. The [std::basic_stringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) allows use of both [std::basic_istream::tellg](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg) and [std::basic_istream::seekg](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg). There are a few caveats:

1. if using the `.str()` member funciton, a copy of the underlying string is returned in a temporary object, there is no change to the seekpos within the stringstream because you are operating on a copy;
2. if using the `rdbuf()` member function, it will return a pointer to the underlying string device. Outputting with  the device will output the contents with and the seekpos will be advanced to the end, but `eofbit` is not set;
3. for normal extractions with `>>` reading the last item in the stringstream sets `eofbit` and `clear()` must be called on the stringstream before seeking further. If `tellg()` is called while the stringstream the streamstate is anything other than `good`, `-1` is returned.

With that a short example exercising `seekg()` and `tellg()` along with `clear()`, where needed, should provide the explanation you are looking for. The is an amalgam of the various examples provided at the links above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
 
int main (void)
{
    std::string str = "Hello, world";         /* initial string */
    std::istringstream in(str);               /* initialized stringstream */
    std::string word1, word2;                 /* two string variables used below */
    
    std::cout << "string: " << in.str() << "\n\ntellg " 
                << std::setw(2) << in.tellg() << " - reading into word1\n";
    
    in >> word1;    /* read into word1 from beginning */
    std::cout << "tellg " << std::setw(2) << in.tellg() << " - after reading \"" 
                << word1 << "\", rewinding\n";
    
    in.seekg (0);   /* seekg beginning (rewind) */
    std::cout << "tellg " << std::setw(2) << in.tellg() << " - reading into word2\n";
    
    in >> word2;    /* read into word2 from beginning */
    std::cout << "tellg " << std::setw(2) << in.tellg() << " - after reading \"" 
                << word2 << "\", reading final word\n";
    
    in >> word2;    /* read into word2 to end of stringstream, eofbit set */
    std::cout << "tellg " << std::setw(2) << in.tellg() << " - after reading \"" 
                << word2 << "\", eofbit set, tellg() fails, must .clear()\n";
    
    in.clear();     /* clear required before further stringstring operations */
    
    in.seekg (0, std::ios_base::beg);   /* reposition to beginning, 2nd form */
    std::cout << "tellg " << std::setw(2) << in.tellg() << " - rdbuf() -> \"" 
                << in.rdbuf() 
                << "\"\ntellg " << std::setw(2) << in.tellg() << " - reversing: \"";
    
    while (in.tellg() != 0) {   /* playing tell & seek back to beginning */
        in.seekg (-1, std::ios_base::cur);          /* seek -1 from current */
        std::cout << (char)in.get();                /* output character */
        in.seekg (-1, std::ios_base::cur);          /* seek -1 from current */
    }
    std::cout << "\"\ntellg " << std::setw(2) << in.tellg() << " - all done.\n";
}
```

**Eample Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/streambuf_seektellg
string: Hello, world

tellg  0 - reading into word1
tellg  6 - after reading "Hello,", rewinding
tellg  0 - reading into word2
tellg  6 - after reading "Hello,", reading final word
tellg -1 - after reading "world", eofbit set, tellg() fails, must .clear()
tellg  0 - rdbuf() -> "Hello, world"
tellg 12 - reversing "dlrow ,olleH"
tellg  0 - all done.
```

The example above shows how to handle manipulation of the streambuf position within the stringstring. From simple rewinds, to handling the streambuf with the read-state other than `goodbit` and how to use combinations of `tellg()` and `seekg()` to iterate over each of the characters in the streambuf from the end to the beginning effectively reversing the output.

---

**Additional Example Using `seekp()` On `std::stringstream`**

In response to your comment, there really isn't much difference, except in order to use the `tellp()` and `seekp()` the `streambuf` object must be able to have output sent to it. That means `tellp()` and `seekp()` are only relevant to `std::stringstream` and `std::ostringstream` but not `std::istringstream`. So in order to position the write location in the example above, you need only change the type to one of two variants that allows output. using `std::stringstream` is fine, e.g.

```
    std::stringstream in(str);          /* stringstrem use both seek&tell (gp) */
```

Now you can move the get and set the write position within it using `tellp()` and `seekp()`. For example the following gets the current read position in `in` by reading again into `word1` and saves the position reported by `in.tellg()`. The position is then used by `seekp()` to position the for a write of `"big wide world!"` after `"Hello, "`, e.g.

```
    std::cout << "\"\ntellg " << std::setw(2) << in.tellg() 
                << " - seeking with seekp() - add \"big wide world!\"\n";
    
    in >> word1;                            /* move past "Hello," */
    size_t pos = in.tellg();                /* save offset from beginning */
    in.seekp (pos + 1);                     /* seekp() past "Hello, " */
    in << "big wide world!";                /* replace remaining content */
    std::cout << "\nstring: " << in.str() << '\n';  /* output result */
```

**Changes to Output**

Changes to the last line of output above and then addition of the new text would result in:

```
...
tellg  0 seeking with seekp() - add "big wide world!"

string: Hello, big wide world!
```

---

**`seekg()`/`tellg()` and  `seekp()`/`tellp()` are Independent Offsets**

In response to your further comments, it is important to understand that the `...g()` and `...p()` member functions provide access to two independent measures of offset from the beginning of the streambuf object. `seekg()` and `tellg()` are associated with the *read position* in the buffer. (think `seek...get()` and `tell...get()`) In contrast, `seekp()` and `tellp()` are associated with the *write position* in the buffer. (think `seek...put()` and `tell...put()`)

An additional change to the final output of the example will make that clear. Change only the line associated with `/* output results */` to:

```
    /* output result */
    std::cout << "\nstring: " << in.str() << "\ntellg  : " << in.tellg()
                << "\ntellp  : " << in.tellp() << '\n';
```

**Changes to Output**

The output now reveals the independent offsets reported by `in.tellg()` and `in.tellp()` after the final writes to `in`, e.g.

```
...
string: Hello, big wide world!
tellg  : 6
tellp  : 22
```

Where `in.tellg()` reports the position in the buffer where the next read (such as `in >> word1;`) will start from, while `in.tellp()` reports the position in the buffer where the next write will take place, (such as `in << " ... of code";`). After adding `in << " ... of code";`, outputting from the current `tellg()` position with `std::cout << '\n' << in.rdbuf() << '\n';`  would result in:

```
 big wide world! ... of code
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you explain how to use the `seekg, seekp, tellg and tellp` on the same `stringstream` variable? In other words, if I have written something to a `stringstream` like so `ss<<word`, since I just wrote something to the `stringstream` I can only use `tellp` on it because it's open in writing mode, do I need to close the `stringstream` like so `ss.close();` before I can use `seekg` on it for reading and getting stream position like so `ss.seekg(0);` `ss>>word2;`? Thanks for your answer, very helpful!

Comment: I have made an addition to the answer explaining what would be needed to use `seekp()` to extend the example shown.

Comment: Thank you so much! Its very clear now. Just one last question, the `get` and `put` positions in `seekg, tellg // get` and `tellp, seekp //put` are not different right? In other words, there is only one file/stream pointer position regardless if we use `seekg` or `seekp`. Like for example, in the new addition to your answer, you used `in.tellg()` to get position from `stringstream` even though you went on to write to the stream later on, the words `big wide world!` instead of using `tellp()` which would be more appropriate since you are about to write to the stream?

Comment: I guess my question is if it is an input and output stream like `stringstream` does it really matter if I use `tellg` or `tellp`?

Comment: Yes, they are two independent measures of offset from the beginning of the streambuf (or file, etc..) `seekg()` and `tellg()` are associated with the *read position* in the buffer. Think `seek...get()` and `tell...get()`. The `seekp()` and `tellp()` are associated with the *write position* in the buffer, think `seek...put()` and `tell...put()`.

Comment: Makes sense now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
std::string word;
std::stringstream ss;

while (word != "n") {
  std::cout << "Enter a word, ( n to stop) : ";
  std::cin >> word;
  std::cin.ignore();
  if (word == "n")
    ss << std::endl;
  else {
    ss << word;
    ss << " ";
  }
}


std::cout << "The content in stringstream is : " << ss.str() << std::endl;

std::cout << "The StreamPositionPosition is: "
          << ss.tellp() << std::endl;  // Yes this is correct, it will give you the position of the current position where you are outputting.

// how should i open the stream to get input from it to store it in a variable?
// If you want to convert it to string simply
std::string str = ss.str();
// If you know the order of the data, you can simply extract it
std::string wordOutput;
ss >> wordOutput;

/* how should I switch the position pointer to a position when I use an
   input/output stream like sstream with seekg(), seekp(), tellg(),tellp() */
/*
seekg sets the position of input
tellg gets the position of input

seekp sets the position of output
tellp gets the position of output
*/

long length = s.tellp(); // gives you the length of the string stream
// If you want the first position do,
 ss.seekp(0);
ss >> wordOutput;
// If you want the third last, do
ss.seekp(length - 3);
ss >> wordOutput;

// Examples for inputs
stringstream example;
example.write ("This is an apple",16);
long pos = example.tellp();
example.seekp (pos-7);
example.write (" sam",4);
// Will result in This is a sample
```

Comment: Can you explain how to use the `seekg, seekp, tellg and tellp` on the same `stringstream` variable? In other words, if I have written something to a `stringstream` like so `ss<<word`, since I just wrote something to the `stringstream` I can only use `tellp` on it because it's open in writing mode, do I need to close the `stringstream` like so `ss.close();` before I can use `seekg` on it for reading and getting stream position like so `ss.seekg(0);` `ss>>word2;`? Thanks for your answer, very helpful!